# OpenGL 3D Mesh Extraction for Linux

Tags: linux, opengl, 3d, open-source

For Windows there are many tools for extracting 3D data from programmes by intercepting the OpenGL data (e.g. 3D Ripper DX, glintercept, Ogle, OpenGLXtractor, HijackGL).

Are there any similar tools for Linux? If not, would it be possible to make one? (and if would anyone be interested in starting an open source project with me?)

I will actually automate the process, but that is another story.

Comment: Yes, there are tools for this. At least there is this OpenGL interceptor library written by another member of my hackerspace. However that tool is not up for the job when it comes to modern OpenGL (doesn't support VBOs, and such).

Comment: 1) There are easier (and more comressed) ways to extract Google Earth data, like intercepting the DEMs that you download.
2) Why not just use their API? Besides needing ~70TB of space to store all the information, your copy would be out of date very quickly.

Comment: @datenwolf What "OpenGL interceptor library" are you referring to? Sounds very interesting.

Comment: @Robert Rouhani Intersecting the data sounds like a good idea. I assume you are referring to the elevation API, but I need the 3D buildings information as well. I will not save all the data, I just need data from some specific places and then process that data before including it in my service.

Comment: The tool `apitrace` currently does not support what you're asking for, but it does have an open task asking for this. Its an opensource project on github, which means there is the potential it may be added soon. If you're interested here is a link to the issue:   [Visualize meshes in draw commands](https://github.com/apitrace/apitrace/issues/2)

Comment: @petter: IIRC it's called `gldump`. It's been written by another member of my [hackerspace](http://muc.ccc.de); I was unable to locate it so far, but I put a message in the chatroom if somebody knows where its sources went.

Comment: If you can't find a good tool for intercepting OpenGL data, there may be other ways to extract data, for example reverse engineering the binary data like it has been done for original games like Tomb Raider (see OpenTomb / OpenLara) and Spyro (the SpyroWorldViewer tool is able to export maps / textures / sky as OBJ file http://klimaleksus.narod.ru/Files/S/SpyroWorld1V2.rar). Another approach that can be used for Spyro games is to use a PlayStation 1 emulator plugin (SpyroEdit https://github.com/LXShades/spyroedit) to extract characters and animations as COLLADA / DAE file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First a word of warning: OpenGL is not a scene graph. There is no such thing as a "scene" or "objects" (in the physical kind of thing sense) in OpenGL. All what OpenGL does is drawing points, lines and triangles to a scene, one at a time and independent from each other. So intercepting OpenGL drawing calls to extract objects by nature is unreliable. That being said most programs using OpenGL do it in a way that make it actually quite feasible to extract the rendered geometry and interpret it as objects.

Another member of my hackerspace wrote a tool for intercepting OpenGL calls to extract meshes (the original use was so that we could 3D print game assets and similar on our RepRap). The sources for this tool can be found here https://github.com/mazzoo/ogldump

However *ogldump* is very limited. It doesn't support vertex buffer objects (VBO), interleaved vertex arrays can mess things up and things like shaders and generic vertex attributes are completely unheared of. Feel free to patch that in, if you like.